# Adding ground to an existing conduit

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, grounding, electrical-panel, conduit

Continuing my basement shop brainstorming...

As I said in another question, the good news is that I've got a 30-amp 240V circuit more or less in the right place and available, and easily accessible for its entire length.

The questionable news is that it's a 3-wire circuit -- no safety ground. It's in conduit, but I never like trusting the continuity thereof.

So: How insane would it be to run a new safety ground *outside* the existing conduit?

... Or should I just scrap the old run and redo it as NMC/Romex?

... Or should I put a GFCI in the new secondary box on principle (probably!), in which case safety ground is mostly moot? I've used that solution for several outlets that had the same problem..

Comment: Seems worth it to just replace the whole thing with a #6/3 w/ ground instead just going through all that trouble for one conductor

Comment: @Kris Sure, if money is no object.

Comment: How long is the run?

Comment: @tester101: The run is about 50 feet. And all exposed.

Comment: @kris: Yeah, probably. Still curious whether code would let me kludge it.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're doing, but if you plan on installing a secondary panel, and are considering pulling new cable. I'd pull larger cable, and install a larger panel. It sounds like you're setting up a workshop, which means a higher capacity might come in handy.

Comment: @tester101: If I'm pulling new cable, then yeah, upsizing probably makes sense. Assuming I can find replacement breakers that fit my old panel. (Electrical supply houses don't usually stock them, annoyingly, but local hardware store tries to keep them around since that make was common for a while in this area.)

Comment: What kind of conduit is the existing wire in? Do wire fill rules prohibit you from pulling a ground wire inside the conduit?

Comment: Yeah, what kind of conduit is the existing wire in? Rigid and EMT behave very differently as a ground conductor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull out the wire that's in conduit, (look it over, but it's probably just fine) pull in that wire and a ground.

It's darn near impossible to pull in another wire without pulling the whole bundle out and back in. It's fairly straightforward to pull the whole bundle out, add a wire and pull back in, unless the conduit is too small.

Code-wise, (250.118) properly installed metallic conduit (RMC, IMC or EMT) is a ground, whether or not you personally like it. It's not copper, but it's got a large cross-sectional area and the fittings are designed to maintain contact if properly installed.

I would not consider Romex an upgrade. I've seen too much rodent/Romex interaction to love it much, and with the possible exception of wire old enough to use cloth-based insulation as primary there's little benefit to "new wire" over "old wire."

Comment: Hmmm. If code accepts it... I need to sanity-check that nobody ha/s done something rude to it, but maybe I should just decide I'm being paranoid?